# how to ignore special characters when using word boundry

Tags: python, regex

```
s = '!sopa !sop !sopaa !sopii'
```

how to ignore `!` when using word boundary

```
re.sub(r'\b\!sop\b', 'sopa', s)
```

output : `'!sopa !sop !sopaa !sopii'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this.

```
>>> s = '!sopa !sop !sopaa !sopii'
>>> re.sub(r'\B!sop\b', 'sopa', s)
'!sopa sopa !sopaa !sopii'
```

Your regex will fail because there isn't a `\b` actually exits before `!` symbol. That is, from the above you're trying to match the `!` symbol only if it's preceded by a non-word character. `\b` matches between a word char and a non-word character, vice versa. `\B` matches between two word and two non-word chars. Here `\B` is actaully exists between a space and `!`, since both are non-word characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:^|(?<= ))!sop\b
```

You can simply use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/bW3aR1/12#python

`re.sub(r'(?:^|(?<= ))!sop\b', 'sopa', s)`

For dynamic string use

```
replace = 'sop'
s = '!sopa !sop !sopaa !sopii'

print re.sub(r"(?:^|(?<= ))!" +replace +r"\b", "new", s)
```

Comment: why it is't working like this , replace = 'sop'; reg = r'(?:^|(?<= ))!' +str(replace) +'\b'; re.sub(reg, replace, s)

Comment: @RizwanMumtaz check updated for dynamic string.Replace `"new"` with whatever you want

Answer (score -1):

Search for non alphanumerical characters and replace by space:

```
re.sub('\W+',' ',s)
```

> ' sopa sop sopaa sopii'